# Maximum number of tuples from $n$ numbers such that no pair is repeated

Tags: co.combinatorics, puzzle

What is the maximum number of $k$-tuples($3\le k\le n$) of $n$ numbers such that no pair is repeated in any of the tuples?

The maximum of number of $k$-tuples occur when $k=\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ as $n\choose \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ is maximum among all binomial coefficients. But, when we give the additional constraint that no pair is repeated twice, I have a hard time in getting the answer. For example, for $n=6$, I think the answer is $4$: the tuples desired are $(123),(145),(246),(356)$. Is it possible that the maximum in this case occurs for $k\neq\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev thanks. what is $r$ of the block design here? I dont put any condition on number of blocs containing any number. And, by the way, isnt my answer right?

Comment: @vidyarthi: Block design represents a uniform construction. Like in your example for $n=6$, you have $r=2$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev but, $r=2$ does not satisfy $\lambda(n-1)=r(k-1)$ right?

Comment: @vidyarthi: It does not because not every pair appears in your example. E.g., there is no pair $1,6$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev so then, the maximum given by my answer is right?

Comment: @vidyarthi: Yes. Each number appear in at most $\lfloor (n-1)/(k-1)\rfloor$ blocks. Then the number of blocks is at most 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k-1}\right\rfloor\right\rfloor.$$
You did achieve this bound in your example for $n=6$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev no, that was ok. I asked about my answer posted below. If not, could you give me an example for, say $n=8$

Comment: This question is a special case of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/175969/an-upper-bound-on-families-of-subsets-with-a-small-pairwise-intersection/176462#176462 .

Comment: @BrendanMcKay ...which further links to https://mathoverflow.net/q/161159/41291 which in turn links to https://mathoverflow.net/q/160787/41291